# Any way to adjust the timeout on Gboard voice to text dialog? It's way too short

Tags: iphone, keyboard, google, voice-dictation

I love the new voice to text feature on Gboard for my iPhone but unless I speak really really fast the dialog disappears before I'm finished speaking. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug with an app developed by Google, not an Apple product.

Comment: @owlswipe ...developed by Google, being used on an Apple device. If we only allowed questions about Apple-produced software, this site would be nearly useless.

Comment: @tubedogg Sure, but this is a question about how Google programmed their app! So this is a basic customer support question that can really only be answered/remedied by **Google's** customer support/engineering team.

Comment: I already posted in SuperUser, and they said I should post over here:
http://superuser.com/questions/1182390/adjusting-the-timeout-on-gboard-voice-to-text?noredirect=1#comment1713239_1182390

Even after all of these years, I am sometimes really confused about which StackExchange site to use. There are so many. I wish there was a single portal that would allow you to search for answers and ask questions about anything, which routed your question based on crowd votes, instead of having the question be downvoted and closed as off topic, with no recourse.

Comment: @owlswipe Whether it's a bug or not is up for debate. The question that is on-topic here is "Is there a setting to change the way this works?" (as stated in the title, though the end of the post asks it in a somewhat different way) If not, then yes, submitting a feature request/bug report/whatever to Google would be the next course of action.

Comment: Yep, **talk to Google about this**.